# Shopware6 App Make services.cart available in Custom Hook

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

services.cart is available in the Cart hook but Request is not available in the Cart hook, so I cannot Form post anything to it.

I created a custom hook, but how can I make services.cart available in my custom hook twig script?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The available data and services for each hook, including custom endpoints, are listed [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference#custom-api-endpoint). Apps cannot change that scope that is provided by the respective hook. If you need a specific service or additional data in a hook, you'll have to implement it in [`platform`](https://github.com/shopware/platform) and make a [pull request](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/code/contribution).

Comment: Thank you. I did that for the cart hook today. I thought there is another way of using the data with custom hooks.